# Making a basic console c# application with a menu based on the key that is pressed

Tags: c#, console

I'm trying to make a program which has two options based on the key is pressed by the user, it'will execute a different action. The second option has to do to displaying some information about operations performed in the first option. The main point is to try to make a navigation menu that the user can come back to the main menu through pressing "ESC" or "Enter" to continue in whatever he chooses

```
Console.WriteLine("\nCAMPAIGN 2022\nSelect what you want to consult:\n1) Votin Urn\n2) DataBase"); // to make clear, database will display info about votes quantity
        int options = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
        if (options == 1)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo menu;
            Console.WriteLine("\nVOTING URN");
            while (exit == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSelect your vote:\n1) Jair Bolsonaro;\n2) Luiz 
                Inacio Lula da Silva;\n3) White;\n4) NulL");
                vote = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                while (vote != 1 & voto != 2 & vote!= 3 & vote != 4)
                {  
                    if (increment == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Vote. Try again:");
                    }
                    vote = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    increment += 1;
```

The thing is: i'm using an if statement and because of local scope when the user selects option 2, to know who have more votes for example, the value is gonna be 0. I tried using switch but it's the same thing. What can I do?

Also, when the user press "ESC" to come back to select "Voting Urn" or "Database" the first letter of the text displayed is cut, like instead of "Campaign" it's "ampaing". I'm using the ConsoleKeyInfo:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press \"Enter\" to continue or \"Escape\" to return to the main menu");
                menu = Console.ReadKey();
                if (menu.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    exit = true;
                }
                if (menu.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    exit = false;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the while loop so it covers the menu aswell and then just add another choice that is "Go back to main menu / exit application" in a swtich statement. And then have everything inside that switch statement and maybe do some fucnctions like TotalVotes() and Vote().Then do create variable names with each person you can vote for and just ++ each variable inside an if statement if they get a vote. Also this is probably a typo? "voto != 2". It seems like your structure is making it harder that it has to for you.